# UNION versus SELECT DISTINCT and UNION ALL Performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there any difference between these two performance-wise?

```
-- eliminate duplicates using UNION
SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Table1 
UNION SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Table2 
UNION SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Table3 
UNION SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Table4 
UNION SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Table5       
UNION SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Table6       
UNION SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Table7       
UNION SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Table8       

-- eliminate duplicates using DISTINCT    
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM
(     
    SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Table1 
    UNION ALL SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Table2 
    UNION ALL SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Table3 
    UNION ALL SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Table4 
    UNION ALL SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Table5       
    UNION ALL SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Table6       
    UNION ALL SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Table7       
    UNION ALL SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM Table8       
) x
```

Comment: Wrapping everything in a "SELECT DISTICT" creates a temporary table which is (kind of) expensive. Other than that I don't see why DISTICNT ... UNION ALL would be faster than (distinct) UNION

Comment: Both show different execution plans in some cases, but same in others, and this is a big confusion now.

Comment: I would trust query optimizer to figure out union

Comment: There is no one answer.  There are many factors which can affect the query plan, including the columns you return and what indexes are in play.  The best approach is to check the query plan on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 65):

The difference between **Union** and **Union all** is that `UNION ALL` will not eliminate duplicate rows, instead it just pulls all rows from all tables fitting your query specifics and combines them into a table.

A **UNION** statement effectively does a `SELECT DISTINCT` on the results set.

If you select Distinct from Union All result set, Then the output will be **equal to** the Union result set.

**Edit:**

**Performance on CPU cost:**

Let me explain with Example:

I have two queries. one is Union another one is Union All

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
GO
 
select distinct * from (select * from dbo.user_LogTime
union all
select * from dbo.user_LogTime) X 
GO

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF

SET STATISTICS TIME ON
GO
 
select * from dbo.user_LogTime
union
select * from dbo.user_LogTime
GO

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
```

I did run the both in same query window in SMSS.
Lets see the **Execution Plan** in SMSS:

[image: The Execution Plan]

What happens is, The query with **Union All** and **Distinct** will take CPU cost more than Query with **Union**.

**Performance on Time:**

`UNION ALL`:

```
(1172 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 39 ms.
```

`UNION`:

```
(1172 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 10 ms,  elapsed time = 25 ms.
```

So **Union** is much better than the Union All with Distinct in **performance-wise**

Comment: I know the outputs will be same for both the queries. My question was on performance difference. Both show different execution plans in some cases, but same in others, and this is a big confusion now.

Comment: What happens if there are about 6 to 8 tables in play?

Comment: I used 11 `UNION` / `UNION ALL` and surprisingly I got `UNION ALL` working faster than `UNION`. With lesser number of tables, the `UNION` seems to be faster. Can you verify this?

Comment: are you using same table or various tables?

Comment: If you are using same tables, It will gives you the same cost or Union all is faster than union. I'd checked with the 5 different tables, Still the Union is faster than union all.

Comment: It is same table repeated 11 times with different columns in selection. No indexes (except the Primary Key) exists on the table. With `UNION` I get `CPU time = 8967 ms,  elapsed time = 800 ms` ... while with `UNION ALL` with `DISTINCT` I get `CPU time = 8845 ms,  elapsed time = 785 ms`

Comment: @PradeepKumar try with different ones

Comment: I tried again with only 1 `UNION`/`UNION ALL` on same table, and still I get the `UNION ALL` working faster! But you get just the opposite. It seems like there is no co-relation between using either of the two cases, w.r.t. performance.

Comment: Can you tell me how many rows in that two tables? and one more thing is if the all rows in both table are unique. then the UNION ALL will be faster, because there is no job for sorting/eliminating rows. so its(UNION ALL) faster in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Another on-point example that illustrates the four possible cases:

```
/* with each case we should expect a return set:
(1) DISTINCT UNION {1,2,3,4,5} - is redundant with case (2)
(2) UNION {1,2,3,4,5} - more efficient?
(3) DISTINCT UNION ALL {1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5} 
(4) UNION ALL {1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5} 
*/

declare @t1 table (c1 varchar(15));
declare @t2 table (c2 varchar(15));

insert into @t1 values ('1'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4');

insert into @t2 values ('2'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5');


select DISTINCT * from @t1 --case (1)
UNION
select DISTINCT * from @t2 order by c1

select * from @t1 --case (2)    
UNION
select * from @t2 order by c1

select DISTINCT * from @t1 --case (3)
UNION ALL
select DISTINCT * from @t2 order by c1

select * from @t1 --case (4)   
UNION ALL
select * from @t2 order by c1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Comparison between **UNION DISTINCT** and **UNION ALL**

This query is used to create an extended employee table with additional alternate IDs for downstream system.  This example comes from a mySQL 8.0.20 enviornment.

For the data and query shown below, tests yielded a significant difference:

```
UNION ALL       8.983 sec  
UNION DISTINCT 15.344 sec
```

To show scale and complexity for this example, table sizes and the query code are shown below

```
hqsource 600K records
accountingemppos 180K 
accountingposld 200K
emp_no_accountingnumeric 20
First UNION block is approx 550K records, second approx 50K

               SELECT a.`emp_no_imported` AS `emp_no`,
              a.`supervisor_emp_no`,
              a.`first name`,
              a.`middle name`,
              a.`last name`,
              a.`jobtitle`,
              a.`status`,
              CASE WHEN rida.`accounting_emp_no` IS NOT NULL THEN
                    rida.`accounting_emp_no`
              ELSE 
                    a.`emp_no_imported`
              END AS `accounting_id`,
              CASE WHEN epfp.`emp_no` IS NOT NULL THEN
                        CASE WHEN `sridf`.`emp_no` IS NOT NULL THEN
                                `sridf`.`accounting_emp_no`
                            ELSE
                                epfp.`emp_no`
                            END
                    ELSE
                        CASE WHEN epp.`emp_no` IS NOT NULL THEN
                            CASE WHEN `srids`.`emp_no` IS NOT NULL THEN
                                `srids`.`accounting_emp_no`
                            ELSE                                        
                                epp.`emp_no`
                            END
                    ELSE
                        CASE WHEN `srida`.`emp_no` IS NOT NULL THEN
                            `srida`.`accounting_emp_no`
                        ELSE
                            a.`supervisor_emp_no`
                        END
                    END
                END AS `accounting_s_emp_no`,
                ep.`emp_no` AS `traas_emp_no`,
                epp.`emp_no` AS `traas_parent_emp_no`
       FROM `hqsource`.hq_people a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `hqsource`.`emp_no_accountingnumeric` `rida` ON `rida`.emp_no = a.`emp_no_imported`
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `hqsource`.`emp_no_accountingnumeric` `srida` ON `srida`.emp_no = a.`supervisor_emp_no`

       LEFT OUTER JOIN `traas`.`accountingemppos_data_extract` ep  ON ep.`emp_no` = a.`emp_no_imported` AND ep.`End` = '2899-12-31' AND ep.`Primary` = 'Y'
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `epe`.`accountingposld_data_extract` p ON p.`RangeGID` = ep.`GID`
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `traas`.`accountingemppos_data_extract` epp  ON epp.`GID` = p.`ParentGID` AND epp.`End` = '2899-12-31' AND epp.`Primary` = 'Y'
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `hqsource`.`emp_no_accountingnumeric` `rids` ON `rids`.emp_no = ep.`emp_no`
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `hqsource`.`emp_no_accountingnumeric` `srids` ON `srids`.emp_no = epp.`emp_no` AND epp.`End` = '2899-12-31' AND epp.`Primary` = 'Y'

       LEFT OUTER JOIN `epe`.`accountingemppos_data_extract_filtered` epf  ON epf.`emp_no` = a.`emp_no_imported` AND epf.`End` = '2899-12-31' AND epf.`Primary` = 'Y'
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `epe`.`accountingposld_data_extract` pf ON pf.`RangeGID` = epf.`GID` 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `epe`.`accountingemppos_data_extract_filtered` epfp  ON epfp.`GID` = pf.`ParentGID` AND epfp.`End` = '2899-12-31' AND epfp.`Primary` = 'Y'
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `hqsource`.`emp_no_accountingnumeric` `ridf` ON `ridf`.emp_no = epf.`emp_no` AND epf.`End` = '2899-12-31' AND epf.`Primary` = 'Y'
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `hqsource`.`emp_no_accountingnumeric` `sridf` ON `sridf`.emp_no = epfp.`emp_no` AND epfp.`End` = '2899-12-31' AND epfp.`Primary` = 'Y'
       WHERE a.`emp_no_imported` REGEXP ('^[a-z]{2}\\d{5}.$') 

UNION ALL
-- UNION DISTINCT

    SELECT a.`emp_no_imported` AS `emp_no`, a.`supervisor_emp_no` AS `s_emp_no`, u.`First_Name`, 'ƒ' AS `MI`, u.`Last_Name`, u.`Job_Title`, NULL AS `status`, 
          CASE WHEN rid.`accounting_emp_no` IS NULL THEN
            ep.`emp_no`
          ELSE 
            rid.`accounting_emp_no`
          END AS `accounting_emp_no`,
          CASE WHEN `srid`.`accounting_emp_no` IS NULL THEN
            epp.`emp_no`
          ELSE
            `srid`.`accounting_emp_no`
          END AS `accounting_s_emp_no`,
          ep.`emp_no` AS `traas_emp_no`,
          epp.`emp_no` AS `traas_parent_emp_no`
    FROM `epe`.`accountingemppos_data_extract_filtered`  ep

    LEFT OUTER JOIN  `hqsource`.`hq_people` a ON a.`emp_no_imported` = ep.`emp_no`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `epe`.`accountingposld_data_extract` p ON p.`RangeGID` =  ep.`GID`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `epe`.`accountingemppos_data_extract_filtered` epp ON epp.`GID` = p.`ParentGID`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `siebel`.`users_all_output` u ON u.`LOGIN` = ep.`emp_no`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `hqsource`.`emp_no_accountingnumeric` `rid` ON `rid`.emp_no = ep.`emp_no`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `hqsource`.`emp_no_accountingnumeric` `srid` ON `srid`.emp_no = epp.`emp_no`
    WHERE 
        ep.`End` = '2899-12-31' AND
        epp.`End` = '2899-12-31' AND
        p.`End` = '2899-12-31' AND
        ep.emp_no REGEXP ('^F\\d{8}$|^V[0-3]\\d{5}$')
        
ORDER BY LENGTH(accounting_emp_no) ASC, accounting_emp_no ASC
```

;

The WHERE clauses in each of the two UNION blocks guarantee the results will be unique.  (This query is years old and runs daily. I wish I had tried this sooner). *Field names have been obfuscated*