# SQL union with joins and without duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL UNION that contains joins but I'm still getting duplicates and I don't want duplicates.

This is the current code I'm trying in SQL Server:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
         e.[Id] AS [Id]
        ,e.[Body] AS [Description]
        ,e.[Subject] AS [Name]
        ,u.UserName AS [UserName]
        ,'email' AS [Type]
        ,e.[RecipientEmailAddress]
        ,e.[CreationTime]
        ,'email' AS [NoteTypeName]
        ,NULL AS [BackGroundClass]
        ,NULL AS [ColourClass]
FROM [dbo].[Emails] e
JOIN [dbo].[AbpUsers] u ON e.UserId = u.Id

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT 
     n.[Id] AS [Id]
    ,n.[Description]
    ,n.[Name]
    ,u.UserName AS [UserName]
    ,'note' AS [Type]
    ,NULL AS [RecipientEmailAddress]
    ,n.[CreationTime]
    ,pnt.[Name] AS [NoteTypeName]
    ,pnt.[BackGroundClass]
    ,pnt.[ColourClass]

FROM [dbo].[Notes] n
JOIN [dbo].[PicklistNoteTypes] pnt ON n.NoteTypeId = pnt.Id
JOIN [dbo].[AbpUsers] u ON n.UserId = u.Id
ORDER BY [Id]
```

The expected result is a result set that doesn't contain duplicates.

The result set:
    [image]

Comment: Post the resuts you get

Comment: Your query will never produce duplicate result as you have already differentiated by `'email' AS [Type]`. & `'note' AS [Type]`.

Comment: the distinct in a UNION is unuseful  the UNION return only distinct result  ,..but DISTINCT in SQL  mean distinct rows for all value.. non distinc value in a column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UNION vs SELECT DISTICT PERFORMANCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35627923/union-versus-select-distinct-and-union-all-performance/35628095)

Comment: I've added the result set I'm getting.

Comment: I don't see any duplicate. Which ones are you seeing?

Comment: NoteTypeName, BackGroundClass and ColourClass columns has duplicates

Comment: The `DISTINCT` clause, as well as the `UNION` operator filter out duplicate **entire rows**, not parts of them. What exactly do you want as the result?

Comment: I want unique rows is this possible?

Comment: They currently are unique.

Comment: If you look at line 14 and 15 NoteTypeName and BackGroundClass are duplicated can I stop that?

Comment: The short answer is no you cannot.  That is why you cannot group by only some of the fields in your select list.  the SQL engine does not know which data you want to keep in the other rows where the data is not duplicated.  I will often use the TSQL functions Row_Number and / or Rank to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks @JoeC for your explaination.