# SQL query not matching any results

Tags: sql, database

I don't know SQL. I read some guides and pieced together this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT K.barcode 
FROM wp_weblib_keywords K, wp_weblib_collection C 
WHERE keyword LIKE Teen 
  AND keyword LIKE 7-12 && K.barcode = C.barcode 
ORDER BY C.barcode ASC
```

I'm trying to find every book that has both keyword "Teen" AND "7-12" (I need the book to have both keywords, not just one or the other). This is how I initialized each table:

```
CREATE TABLE weblib_keywords 
(
     keyword VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
     barcode varchar(16) not null check (barcode <> ''),
     KEY (keyword) 
) CHARACTER SET utf8;

CREATE TABLE weblib_collection 
(
     barcode varchar(16) not null unique check (barcode <> ''),
     title varchar(128) not null check (title <> ''),
     author varchar(64) not null check (author <> ''),
     PRIMARY KEY (barcode),
     KEY (title),
     KEY (author)
) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

I think the problem is I'm not telling SQL which table to search in, but I'm not sure how to write that. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `UNION` based on your data volume.

```
SELECT K.barcode FROM wp_weblib_keywords K 
inner join wp_weblib_collection C
on K.barcode = C.barcode
WHERE keyword LIKE '%Teen%' 
UNION
SELECT K.barcode FROM wp_weblib_keywords K 
inner join wp_weblib_collection C
on K.barcode = C.barcode
WHERE keyword LIKE '%7-12%'
```

[Why UNION ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35627923/union-versus-select-distinct-and-union-all-performance#:%7E:text=3%20Answers&text=The%20difference%20between%20Union%20and,combines%20them%20into%20a%20table.&text=If%20you%20select%20Distinct%20from,to%20the%20Union%20result%20set.)

Edit:

If you only need both of them try below. For the same line if you try `LIKE` and `AND` together it will give you no result. You should consider joining the same table again with different alias and check your constraints seperately.

```
SELECT c.barcode FROM wp_weblib_keywords K1 
inner join wp_weblib_collection C
on K1.barcode = C.barcode
inner join wp_weblib_keywords K2 
on K2.barcode = C.barcode
WHERE k1.keyword LIKE '%Teen%' and k2.keyword LIKE '%7-12%' 
group by c.barcode
```

Comment: Will this get me "Teen" AND "7-12" or "Teen" OR "7-12"? I need the first one

Comment: You will get only 'Teen' plus only '7-12' with using this. If there are records which contain both 'Teen' and '7-12' you will get those record both ways of union (below and above) but their barcode will be singularize. @JasonC.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below - with the like operator you need to wildcard character `'%'`

```
SELECT DISTINCT K.barcode FROM wp_weblib_keywords K inner join wp_weblib_collection C
on K.barcode = C.barcode
WHERE keyword LIKE '%Teen%' OR keyword LIKE '%7-12%' 
order by C.barcode
```

Comment: That worked, but when I change the OR to AND, it still has no results. I already verified that I have some books with keyword Teen and 7-12

Comment: for the single column, using different condition with AND will not show you any result, you need OR condition @JasonC.

Answer (score 1):

If the semantics of the wp_weblib_keywords_table is to include a single keyword in each row, then this query will never return results (apart from formatting issues.)

The reason is that the query looks at each row in the wp_weblib_keywords table and tries to find a single row where the keyword is two separate values.  Well, a single row in a table will never have a column that equals two separate values.

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.barcode 
FROM wp_weblib_collection C
INNER JOIN join wp_weblib_keywords K1 on C.barcode = K1.barcode 
INNER JOIN wp_weblib_keywords K2 on c.barcode = K2.barcode
WHERE k1.keyword = 'Teen' AND k2.keyword = '7-12' 
ORDER BY C.barcode
```

That query will return rows if there is one record with keyword 'Teen' and another record with keyword = '7-12'

Comment: This seems like the right idea, and I will try it, but where did you define K? Other than that, it seems good.

Comment: Sorry, I changed K to C.  Please try it now.

Comment: This will not give the right result because you are looking `keyword` column using `=` operator. You should use `LIKE` instead.@crosen9999

Comment: If the semantics of the wp_weblib_keywords table are to have one keyword per row, then = is the correct operator @ismetguzelgun