# How to count DISTINCT occurrences of a single value across two different columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table called "match" with these columns:

```
id | matcher | partner | meetup | date | block | delay | started | rejected
```

My goal is extract count of distinct users in a month format like this:

```
  month  | monthly_users
---------+---------------
 2021-12 |             4
 2022-02 |             6
```

The problem is that the users are in two columns: **matcher** and **partner**, meaning that I have to count only values that are distinct accross those two columns because a single user can be both in matcher and partner fields.

For example

```
id | matcher | partner | meetup | date | block | delay | started | rejected
1  | user 1 | user 2| ...
2  | user 3 | user 1| ...
```

**I want to count user 1 only ONE time in THAT MONTH.**

I've done it for a single column like this:

```
select 
TO_CHAR(date_trunc('month', "date"), 'YYYY-MM') AS month, 
COUNT(DISTINCT "matcher") AS unique_matchers
from match
GROUP BY month;
```

But failed for both columns, here is my attempt:

```
select
TO_CHAR(date_trunc('month', "date"), 'YYYY-MM') AS month,
count(user) AS monthly_users
from ((select DISTINCT matcher as user, date from match) union all
      (select DISTINCT partner as user, date from match)
     ) as derived
GROUP BY user, month;
```

Comment: Option 1) Create a inline view or CTE which unions the needed columns into one linear dataset.  so.... `SELECT "date", "matcher from match union all Select "date", user from match` then do you r query like you would for a single column  Option 2) you could use a self join/ full outer join and join the two based on YYYY-MM and matcher & user and then coalesce the null out. then your count(distinct coalesce(matcher,user)) would give you the right value when grouped...  Not sure which would be more efficient...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join 2 selects in a sub-query using UNION ALL

```
SELECT
p.month,
COUNT( p.player) monthly_users
FROM
(
SELECT 
TO_CHAR(date_trunc('month', "date"), 'YYYY-MM') AS month, 
matcher AS player
FROM match
UNION 
SELECT 
TO_CHAR(date_trunc('month', "date"), 'YYYY-MM') AS month, 
partner AS player
FROM
) p
GROUP BY p.month
ORDER BY p.month;
```

Comment: get rid of the `all` in union all  and you don' need the count `distinct`

Comment: @xQbert : there can be 2 players in one of the 2 halves of the subquery, which wouldn't be eliminated by union. As union all doesn't eliminate there is no comparison and it runs faster than union (irrelevant pour 5 lines but could be important for a large number, especially if there is no usable index)

Comment: Pretty sure `union` does a `distinct` after the sets have been merged so if duplicates exist within one or both sets, they all get consolidated down to 1 after the union.  The reason the Union is slower is because of the distinct it does to eliminate duplicates. [Example Union](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=57d13be3e1def036c48d2d0bacd35c8c)  with regards to performance.  I'd have to test. I don't know if the count(distinct) on a union set would be faster or the distinct done within the union.

Comment: @xQbert : you are quite right see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d3e98262fe77c3597bae7f1a4788353a Thank you for the adjustment

Comment: we all learn from eachother.  I can't say which way is "better" without testing.  So what you've done may be faster; or it may be faster to do the union... would have to test using large datasets...

Comment: @xQbert  I've tried with `EXPLAIN` and there is a slight improvment with UNION compared to COUNT(DISTINCT)  95 instead of 97. Thanks again - have a good evening.

Comment: @kendal good to know thanks!  I was just reading up on it and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35627923/union-versus-select-distinct-and-union-all-performance  which shows similar findings.  Be well.

Answer (score 1):

Your try was ok.
Instead of union all just use union and in this way you will have distinct values. No need for use of DISTINCT

```
select TO_CHAR(date_trunc('month', "date_c"), 'YYYY-MM') AS month
       , count(user) AS monthly_users
from ((select matcher as usera, date_c from match) union
      (select partner as usera, date_c from match)
     ) as derived
GROUP BY  month;
```

also I have changed word user into usera because it is a keyword.

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d94efb65cd645b86426cb504e3ecb9f7)

Here is a new code after I have read the correct comments...

```
select TO_CHAR(date_trunc('month', "month"), 'YYYY-MM')
       , count(usera) AS monthly_users
from (select matcher as usera, date_trunc('month', "date_c") AS month 
      from match 
      union
      select partner as usera, date_trunc('month', "date_c") AS month
      from match
      group by usera, month) as derived
GROUP BY  month;
```

[Here is a new DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2e4df0dff57ac5a8dd626de04a204589)

I see also that this is the same as accepted answer....

Comment: Where does count(user) come from? Shouldn't that be count(usera)? 
I have tried this but for some reason it also counts duplicate appearances.

Comment: Not sure how duplicates would be eliminated with the union.  since "date_c" is a date and 1/1/2020 and 1/2/2020 would report the same user twice, which I think is undesired.  one would have to do the month / year evaluaion iside the union to make that work I think.

Comment: I've tried with 3 different dates and it lists 6 users : see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=768a99699707705dc89c49eec728ce8e

Comment: Hi @failedCoder thanks. I have added new code. Will arrange my answer when I will be at my pc.

Comment: Hi @Kendle thanks for your comment. I see you provided the answer. Cheers